# How to store list of tuples in django model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am working on a food recipe database web app in Django 4 and want to store an unknown number of ingredients required for a recipe within a given model. The ingredient is described by a name, a volume, and a measuring unit - eg: Sugar 400 grams, Eggs 2 pieces, etc. I am using PostgreSQL

What is the best practice to store such data within a given model while preserving the ability to query the data or do arithmetic operations on the volumes of the ingredients please?

I have found two options so far, but since I am very new to web development, I do not know if they could work:

1. Create a separate model for ingredient and use a many-to-many relationship to connect the models but this would create a new object for every instance that for instance volume is different
2. Just use TextField() and then use some crazy Regex to separate the ingredients out

Given that I am new to web development, I have no clue what is the most suitable option.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Create a separate model for ingredient and use a many-to-many relationship...

Many-to-Many relationships are useful when you want to filter recipes by their ingredients. For example, to list all the recipes which contain Eggs or Sugar.

If you want this feature, then you'll have to use many-to-many field.

> ... but this would create a new object for every instance that for instance volume is different

Many-to-Many fields support a `through` argument which allows you to pass an intermediate model to hold the extra data to avoid this problem. See [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in docs.

---

> 2. Just use TextField() and then use some crazy Regex to separate the ingredients out

If you don't want to filter by ingredients, using a [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) is a better choice than `ManyToManyField` or `TextField`. This will allow you to store data in a structured format, for example:

```py
ingredients = [
    {'name': 'Sugar', 'qty': '400 grams'},
    {'name': 'Egg', 'qty': '1'},
    ...
]
```

---

P.S.: If you're going to use `JSONField`, also take a look at a library I've created called [`django-jsonform`](https://github.com/bhch/django-jsonform) which is useful for creating user-friendly JSON editing forms in the admin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I wanted to use JSON, it wouldnt be possible to filter by ingredient due to how JSON is being handled in the database? What are the caveats of using JSON within models?

Comment: @MajorPig Django does support querying JSON ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)), though it's not as good as regular SQL querying. I suggest you try both the methods and see which suits your use case better.